# castle windsor named component registration order

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm having an issue trying to resolve named components. Per the Castle documentation, it states that when more than one components have the same dependency, the first registered component is chosen first. [Register more components for the same service](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Registering-components-one-by-one&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

To avoid that, I use named components to resolve them for the same dependency.

```
container.Register(Component.For<DataContext>().ImplementedBy<MyContext>()
   .Named("Db1").DependsOn(Property.ForKey<string>()
   .Eq(Configuration.ConnectionStrings["Db1"].ConnectionString)));

container.Register(Component.For<DataContext>().ImplementedBy<MyContext>()
   .Named("Db2").DependsOn(Property.ForKey<string>()
   .Eq(Configuration.ConnectionStrings["Db2"].ConnectionString)));
```

and then call `kernel.Resolve<DataContext>(cbo.SelectedItem.ToString());` where `cbo` is a `ComboBox` conrtol, I always get the first component registered no matter which option is selected.

Comment: don't you need the name of the property in `Property.ForKey<string>([propertyName])` ?

Comment: When I step through in debug mode, I get the desired connection string being set in MyContext except I always end up with the first component registered.

Comment: Are you sure "cbo.SelectedItem.ToString()" is returning either "Db1" or "Db2"?

Answer (score 1):

This was too much to put in a comment.  Windsor version 3 supports what you want to do.  Here's what I tried and it worked:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly string item;

    public Foo(string item) { this.item = item; }

    public string Name { get { return this.item; } }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().Named("F1").DependsOn(Property.ForKey<String>().Eq("one")));
    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().Named("F2").DependsOn(Property.ForKey<String>().Eq("two")));

    var f1 = container.Resolve<IFoo>("F1");
    var f2 = container.Resolve<IFoo>("F2");
}
```

The variable `f1` referenced the instance with the item of "one" and `f2` referenced the instance with the item of "two".  Could you create a failing test case that highlights your issue?

Comment: Patrick, I did the same as what you posted in your answer. Both DataContext objects resolve as expected based on their respective names. While I digging through the local variables, I noticed that my repository classes, the name in the Castle.Core.ComponentModel all resolve to the first registered DataContext in my container. Do I need to write my own ISubDependencyResolver to fix this?